# Why does mongo still throw error when I am handling error with if statement

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am deliberately trying to create duplicate key error by following code.

```
let repoTemplate = new RepoTemplate({
    name: templateName,       //mongoose schema - unique
    creator: req.user.username,
    sheetsInfo: {
        calc: calcObj,
        result: resultsObj,
        data: dataObj,
        reference: referecneObj
    }
});

repoTemplate.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
        logger.error(messageCreator.log.error.saveError(req.user.username, curRoute, 'repoTemplate', err));
        //TODO error handling
        return res.json({success: false});  //Throws error
    }
})
```

`repoTemplate` is a mongoose unique field and I am deliberately using name that already exists in `Mongodb`. Although I am handling error with if statement, error is still thrown at `return res.json({success:false})` and application stops.

Why is this? and how can I catch this error properly?

Comment: what do you mean by "error is still thrown at return res.json({success:false}) and application stops" ? Do you mean if(err)  is true ?

Comment: @divine yes if(err) is true the application proceeds until `return res.json(...)` but still throws error so express exits

Comment: @divine I also get response code `500` instead of `{success:false}`

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: `duplicated key error at repoTemplate.name` which is what I did intend for.

Comment: Are you sure that the error message you have mentioned is thrown from inside the if(err) block ?

Comment: @divine yes I am certain because I have debugged it down to `return` line